# SonarQube C# file is not analyzing with lates C# 6.3(build 2862) plugin

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am not able to analyze C# code with the latest C# plugin it is working fine 5.5 version plugin.
with the latest plugin i am getting the following warning

[06:25:02][Step 5/5] 06:25:02.489 INFO  - Importing analysis results from C:\BuildAgent\work\fb3239136ebc26fc\null\output-cs
[06:25:02][Step 5/5] 06:25:02.516 WARN  - Protobuf file not found: null\output-cs\encoding.pb
[06:25:02][Step 5/5] 06:25:02.523 WARN  - Protobuf file not found: null\output-cs\metrics.pb
[06:25:02][Step 5/5] 06:25:02.525 WARN  - Protobuf file not found: null\output-cs\issues.pb
[06:25:02][Step 5/5] 06:25:02.528 WARN  - Protobuf file not found: null\output-cs\token-type.pb
[06:25:02][Step 5/5] 06:25:02.531 WARN  - Protobuf file not found: null\output-cs\symrefs.pb
[06:25:02][Step 5/5] 06:25:02.533 WARN  - Protobuf file not found: null\output-cs\token-cpd.pb
[06:25:02][Step 5/5] 06:25:02.533 INFO  - Sensor C# [csharp] (done) | time=59ms

But with Sonar-C# plug 5.8 I am getting the proper results for C# code.

SonarQube Version:6.4

I am using Sonar Scanner feature as well.

Using TeamCity for the build.

Comment: You've given almost nothing to go on. Please [edit] your question to include error logs at the very least, if not also details on project type.

Comment: @Team, please check the logs.

Comment: Still nothing to go on @chandra. You've shown log warnings, but they're only advisory.

Comment: there my problem lies i don't get any info on this, I tried all solutions which are on google, finally, i had to revert to the older version of the plugin and my analysis starts.